# How to resize a BLOB image stored in my SQLite database?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, tkinter, blob

I'm trying to resize a **BLOB** picture stored in my database, because when I save the original photo in my database as **BLOB** I used resize command `im = im.resize((170, 170), Image.ANTIALIAS)` but it seems that it doesn't work and just save the original picture's size in my database, so the only option I was thinking is to adjust the size of my imagen stored in my database before display it into my frame but I have no idea how to do it. Here is the code:

```py
def show(data):
    img_byte = BytesIO(data)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(img_byte))
    Label(frame_form3, image=img).place(x=1, y=1)
    top.image = img
```

Any advise please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Why not fix the image resize code so it saves successfully?

Comment: You already know how to use `Image.resize()` from `pillow` module, so what is the problem actually.

Comment: Try `img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(img_byte).resize((170, 170), Image.ANTIALIAS)`. ?

Comment: Thanks guys, It's working good now

Comment: @CoolCloud I tried it and worked, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `resize` on any `Image` objects, like:

```py
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(img_byte).resize((170, 170), Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

Or the more readable version:

```py
im = Image.open(img_byte) # Open
im = im.resize((170, 170), Image.ANTIALIAS) # Change size
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im) # Make PhotoImage
```